# Trying to find a jpeg file in a raw file taken from a memory card with C

Tags: c

Hi I am trying to find a jpegs inside a raw file

I was told the beginning of each jpeg starts with either 
 - 0xff 0xd8 0xff 0xe0 
 - 0xff 0xd8 0xff 0xe1

So I am doing this:

```
// open input file 
FILE* inptr = fopen("card.raw", "r");

// create an array to hold info read from the memory card
char buffer[512];


int counter=0;
int counter2=0;


while ((fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 512, inptr)!=0))
{

    if(buffer[0]==0xff)
    {
        counter++;
        printf("%2d - Found a jpeg!\n", counter);

    }

    else 
    {   
        //Just to test
        counter2++;
        printf("%2d - Nothing Found!\n", counter2);
    }
}
```

But even though I am certainly sure there are some images there, the program is not finding anything.  Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: You could have a compressed file system (or archive) on that sdcard. And your code seems to search sectors starting with 0xff, but I would imagine the image could start at an arbitrary (non-multiple of 512) offset.

Comment: You should use photorec instead.

Comment: RAW files (which vary greatly depending on the manufacturer of the image capture device, and are not always well documented) are typically a proprietary format image file, not just a container for other image formats. As such, given the right software, they can probably be *converted* to a JPEG file, but they don't necessarily *contain* a JPEG file.

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer!!, I needed to declare buffer as an unsigned char like this:

```
unsigned char buffer[512];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unsigned char is more natural for this case, but if you wanted to keep using signed char (simple "char" may or may not be signed depending on the environment, better to be explicit), then, instead of using 0xff, you could've compared with -1:

```
if(buffer[0]==-1)
```

That said, I would, probably, have [mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mmap)-ed the entire file once and then looped through the allocated memory.

And, finally, since you are looking not just for 0xff, but for the entire sequence indicating beginning of a JPEG, use [memmem()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memmem) searching for the entire sequence in the mmap-ed area. Doing so would've also dealt with the possibility of the JPG file beginning not at the beginning of a 512-block.